# Serilog SQL Server sink with custom table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I am using SeriLog SQL Server sink. I am using `appsettings.json` to read the configuration for the Serilog.

I have a custom log table with custom columns (Id, Info). So I need to save Serilog message into the `Info` column. Is this possible using only app settings configuration without changing the source code?

I know this is possible by the property to log context. But I don't need to change the source code if so I have to review 500 code lines where it is used to log.

If it is only possible by adding property to logcontext then is it possible to map Message => Info column globally using the source code?